# Is my approach correct for Android's Material Design implementation?

Tags: android, material-design

I have my app UI something like below but with a difference being it's a deck of flash cards.

[image]

Now that means I'm making use of material design principles and features. My questions are:

- Where should the FloatingActionButton be placed (in activity_main.xml or fragment_main.xml), when the point is to add/remove cards to favourites list, that can be reviewd later.
- Where should the TextView element be placed (in activity_main.xml or fragment_main.xml)?

I intend to use ViewPager for swiping cards. And construct the entire UI as part of the fragment_main.xml. And I avoid the temptation of using AppBarLayout and Toolbar; instead use the regular ActionBar.

As I see things this would make code design simple and easy to maintain. Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do is to continue taking advantage of fragments for any and all content that is going to share the same layout while also being somewhat independent.

Fragments are reusable, modular bits that can be placed in many activities, For example an `Action Bar` with an "Add to Favorites Button" used on all Activities can 'live' in its own fragment.

You can define many different Fragments as well, that is, one for the Action Bar named `fragment_actionbar` and another named `fragment_flashcard`, each with the needed space and items for information. This gives you further freedom down the road, for example leaving a `fragment_actionbar` off of layouts bigger than a certain size/density. This will allows you to "make code design simple and easy to maintain."

[More on Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

As for Material Design, As long as you are taking advantage of the principles taught and shared inline with Material Design, you are following the practice. Broadly, Material Design asks creators to make designs with paper and ink as inspiration, with light, surface and movement being the key drivers to this design approach. Simple Shadows, Bold and Solid Colors, Motion as Meaning, Large Type and utilizing Negative Space are also characteristics of Material Design. Best advise, stick with Androids predefined modules for now and materiel design practices are already being followed/utilized.

[More on Material Design](https://material.google.com/#introduction-goals)